# Why does the part that is sculpted with Snake Hook look ugly?

Tags: modeling, vertices, sculpting

Whenever I use the Snake Hook tool for sculpting in blender, this is how my shape turns out: (stretched, some vertices are missing and very bad)

[image]

Comment: The result will completely depend on your mesh density, unless you've enabled Dyntopo, in that case it will create new vertices

Comment: Thanks man! would u post this comment of yours as an answer? since It was actually the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Snake Hook's Active Tool and Workspace settings you should probably have Dyntopo and Smooth Shading checked, with a lower Detail Size than the 12px default:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The result will completely depend on your mesh density, the *Snake Hook* brush won't create any new vertices, unless you've enabled the *Dyntopo* option.